# How to detect if the receiver exit suddenly a video call

Tags: java, android, agora.io

I'm using Agora RTC and Signaling SDK for building a video call function.
But I get a problem that if the receiver side exits app suddenly (like swiping app out from recent tray).
Then, the caller side is still on calling screen and can not get any event from receiver side to end the video call.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem, you need to add leave channel logic at onDestroy method in receiver's activity. So that when the receiver exits the app, he will leave the channel and that will notify the caller.